How to render to template ref with markdown-it
I am trying to make a markdown-enabled blog page with markdown-it in Vue. How can I get the markdown to render inside of a template ref?
import { useTemplateRef, onMounted } from 'vue';
import markdownit from 'markdown-it';

const md = markdownit();

onMounted(() => {
  md.render("# Test");
});

md.render will add it to the body element, there is also md.parse but that doesn't return html. I am not attached to markdown-it so if you think there is a better parser for the job suggest that instead.

hope this article helps https://dev.to/matijanovosel/rendering-markdown-in-vue-3-3maj

Yes this helped, thank you
